# Facebook Like Button Discrepancy Between Application, Website and New Community Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have a live website currently (www).

About 4 months ago we launched a Facebook Application (FB APP) that introduced our product.  At that time we created a "like" button that is connected to (www).  There are currently 80 likes when I look at the app page.

Within the past month Facebook created, what I believe is called a "Community Page" (FBCP).  I believe that this is just an interface that allows me to communicate with people who "like" my (www).  Nobody else can see this page (Not a Fan Page). This pages says that I have 30 "likes" currently.

I have a checkout page on (www) that has a "like" counter that we generated based on (www).  This counter about 3 weeks ago had about 110 "likes" on it.  Recently the number has dropped to 80.  It was about 110 and now 80.

My questions are...

1. Did something change with how Facebook looks at the community page vs the website (www) and separate the likes between each?
2. Is there a way to merge both groups together?
3. Is there a way for me to claim the Community page or convert to a Fan Page?  FB says yes, but the documentation on doing this seems out of date and I can't get to links they document actually exist.
4. What distinguishes FBCP "likes" vs www "likes".  Some of the people are in both???

Answer (score 1):

The count on the like button is a combination of a number of actions including "liking" the page web page and "sharing" the webpage (e.g. via a copy and paste into Facebook.com or use of a share dialog. ( Ref: end of second paragraph https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ )

The count on the Admin Page (or FBCP as you are calling it) is just a count of those who have clicked the like button only.

If you have everything linked by an app ID (e.g. domain claimed by app ID etc) then you may want to create a publicly visible "App Page" on Facebook.com via the "Create Facebook Page" button at the bottom of the advanced menu in the developer app: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

If you need any more help it would be easiest if you supply the URL for the WWW and FBCP as well.

Comment: Okay, using the graph API explorer I think you can look at this '156616721134608' - That is the id in question. (This is the dev of the site the OP is the site owner.) Right now I just did a test and clicked the like button @ https://www.fdanconia.com/checkout -- It went up but the number did not change on that ID. I don't even know what that ID is referring to or why the numbers on it seem completely stagnant. Also, even more frustrating we cannot figure out where it is getting that 'description' and 'about' from.

Comment: Jonathan, thanks for the reply.  So a little more background.  We have an app that we used and had a "like" button that was tagged to www.fdanconia.com our website.  After 30 people liked, a new page showed up at http://www.facebook.com/pages/F-dAnconia-Brownies-Gourmet-Mailorder-Brownie-Gifts/156616721134608  this has an admin portion and also a "fan page" looking part at the bottom.  I am the admin for this page.  How do I publish this as the fan page?  Also, I invite people and they don't seem to get the invites.  So it feels like FB highjacked my page/brand.  I can't edit anything on this.

Comment: By the way, thank for looking at this.  Just am amazed at the lack of documentation on this new page.

Comment: What you have there is an Open Graph Admin page. It is the page on facebook which represents the page on your www. The like count on that page is the number of people who have clicked the like button on your web site. The like count on your web site is the combination of the number of people who have clicked like on your web site or shared the link by some other means on Facebook. Hence the discrepancy. Instead of having the like button to your www, I would recommend that you point it at the Public FB page which represents your app. That way likes on your WWW will also be likes on you FB page.

Comment: @Jonathan - The issue is that the like count on the open graph admin page has not moved past 30 for about 3-4 weeks while we KNOW that people have clicked the like button on the site and the count on the site is moving up. Yes, it is also moving up from shares as well, however, the like count on the open graph admin page has not budged. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Jonathan, Brandon is working with me on this.  

On another note, with the Admin page it states I can invite people to this page and I have invited family members and they have not received a notification on their end.  Where would they be notified and is this a known issue?

Comment: Hi Andy, that sounds like a bug.Only admins can see that page so sending invites to non-admins will never work.

Comment: Bummer... Don't take this personally but that would seem to be a "P0" bug.  I don't get the use of this page if the invite feature doesn't work.  Thanks for your help.